# Nginx and Catch for Sub Domain with PHP

Tags: php, nginx

In Nginx, I have a catch all set up like this:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  *.example.com;

    location / {
        root   /data/sites/www.example.com/widgets/public_html;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ .php$ {
      root          /data/sites/www.examples.com/widgets/public_html;
      fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_index  index.php;
      include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

And if I type abc.example.com it works. Now in PHP I need to the subdomain to be read. I am getting the subdomain like so:

```
$url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$urlSegments = parse_url($url);
$urlHostSegments = explode('.', $urlSegments['host']);
$subdomain = $urlHostSegments[0];
```

The problem is, instead of returning with **abc** as the subomain, it returns the *****. So for PHP and NGINX, how can I get the actual subdomain with a catch all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
array_shift(explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print_r($_SERVER);
```

to know the *right* variable.

which is `HTTP_HOST`, not `SERVER_NAME` of course